# How to make passing an array by reference optional in C++ function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, arguments

Is there a way to pass default value to array which is passed by reference to a function so that passing it is not necessary?

I have a function like this:

```
void foo(int (&arr) [3])
{
    //some code...
}
```

Then i tried this:

```
void foo(int (&arr) [3] = nullptr)
{
    //some code...
}
```

but it obvoiusly didn't work because reference cannot be `nullptr` and it is not even an array.

EDIT:
I would like not to use `std::array` if possible, and I also need to know the size of passed array without passing its size which is why I didn't do this: `int (*arr)[3]`.

Comment: Probably simpler to write a separate overload of `foo` that doesn't take an argument.

Comment: Pass a pointer `int (*arr)[3] = nullptr`?

Comment: `void foo() { int dummy[3]; foo(dummy); }`

Comment: Pass a `std::array` by pointer maybe?

Comment: Reopened since the "duplicate" doesn't answer how to use a default argument, which is the whole point of this question.

Comment: Also consider `void foo(const int (&arr)[3] = { 1, 2, 3 })` if you don't need to modify the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, you cannot directly pass a default value to an array passed by reference. However, you can achieve a similar effect by overloading the function with a version that accepts a default array and calls the original function with it.

Here is a Code

```
void foo(int (&arr)[3]){}

void foo()
{
    int defaultArr[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    foo(defaultArr);
}
int main()
{
    int arr[3] = {2, 1, 4};
    foo(arr); 

    foo();     
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I also need to know the size of passed array without passing its size which is why I didn't do this: `int (*arr)[3]`.

This explanation doesn't make sense to me. The array size is encoded in the pointer type. Simply indirect through the pointer and you get a `int (&arr) [3]`. Example:

```
void foo(int (*arr)[3] = nullptr)
{
    if (arr)
        std::cout << std::size(*arr);
    else
        std::cout << "nullptr";
}
```

As such, using a pointer to array is an answer to your question.

Another option is to use an optional span:

```
void foo(std::optional<std::span<int, 3>> arr = std::nullopt)
```

While the parameter type is a bit more verbose, this allows you to pass an array directly without using the addressof operator. Furthermore, this allows passing other contiguous ranges too, not just arrays.

---

If you know at compile time that you want the default option, then I recommend using the overload solution in Syed's answer, but that won't work if the option is determined at runtime.

Comment: Ehh "The array size is encoded in the pointer type" - not really; you cannot get the size of an array from a pointer. You'd need a `std::array` or `std::vector` for that - with a `.size()` member you can call.

Comment: @JesperJuhl `you cannot get the size of an array from a pointer.` Yes, you can get the size from a pointer to array. `You'd need a std::array or std::vector for that` No, you don't need those.

Comment: please demonstrate getting the array size from just a pointer to the first element of an array . *Prove* me wrong.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I added an example.

Comment: @JesperJuhl `from just a pointer to the first element of an array` Your mistake is thinking that `int (*arr)[3]` is a pointer to the first element of an array. It is **not**. It is a pointer to the whole array.

Comment: @JeJo True, but then we have a template, which OP might need to avoid. But if template is not an issue, then it's good for generality indeed. The optional span version can be templated similarily.

Comment: @JeJo `std::optional might require the caller side also to change/ use/ convert the arrays to optional type as well` The conversion is implicit and trivial.

Comment: @eerorika Okay thanks, sorry that i didn't saw edit.